# url rewrite working on localhost, but not on remote server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

url rewrite statement is working on localhost, but not on remote server.

Here is my rewrite statement:

```
RewriteRule ^financial-research/papers/([0-9]+)/(.+)/$ /financial-research.php?c=1d1&i=$1
```

I am trying to redirect:

```
www.mysite.com/financial-research/papers/109/financial-lending/
```

to

```
/financial-research.php?c=1d1&i=$1
```

Comment: Check if rewrite rule is ON on your server or not. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

to redirect to another url you can try header:

```
<?php
    header("Location: www.mysite.com/financial-research.php?c=1d1&i=$1");
?>
```

Comment: I hope you saw the question properly because he is trying to rewrite the URL not redirect to another page.